# Build ionic on Android "Could not compile settings file '***/platforms/android/settings.gradle'"

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an ionic app on Android in Visual Studio on Mac, but I'm getting this error:

```
sudo ionic cordova build android  --warning-mode=all
```

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.        
    * Where:
    Settings file '/Users/**/platforms/android/settings.gradle'
    * What went wrong:
    Could not compile settings file '/Users/**/platforms/android/settings.gradle'.
    > startup failed:
    General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 62
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62 

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Command failed with exit code 1: /**/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /**/platforms/android/build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

Version I have used:

1. `./gradlew wrapper version= 7.3.1`
2. `gradle version= 7.3.1`
3. `java version= 11.0.15.1`

from `Info.plist` file of android studio:

`JVMVersion= 11.0.12`

Answer (score 0):

Unsupported class file major version 62 means that Java 16 is not yet supported.
Try Java 8 or 11 instead (eg. Android Studio's bundled version) by editing file gradle.properties and adding org.gradle.java.home=you'r 11 java path

Comment: I have changed java to 8 but not worked, my gradle.properties file only contains: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: did you added in your gradle.properties  like this : org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk_xxx

Comment: I'm using mac so I have write this command: "/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8" and put the output path in the same location you have mentioned  
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home, and the same error appears