# ionic cordova prepare android: resources/ directory already exists

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cmd

I just created an ionic app which I already started successfully in the browser using this command:

```
ionic serve
```

I get the following warning when running

```
ionic cordova prepare android
```

[image]

Why does this warning appear, why do I already have this resources directory and why is this a problem? What is the correct thing to do here? (Yes/No?)

Comment: Because you are running cordova prepare command, its re-setting up your files.  Why are you using prepare? if you select Yes, what happens?

Comment: it happened using either command (also with ionic cordova emulate android). I edited my question.

when I select y or N, I get this error once I emulate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641747/build-ionic-on-android-could-not-compile-settings-file-platforms-android-s

I thought preventing the warning that I get here might solve my other issue. But the other issue is not my question here

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using : `ionic cordova run android`. More info here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run

Comment: I am facing the same warning (and after I am also facing the same errors) after running this. I think both commands to the same thing in the end.

I think I know what my actual problem was with the error:
I am not using the correct java version to run with gradle & android here. I will try to change it again (even though I failed at  changing it last time)